# Which could be the best way for communication of Micro-services without any HARD-CODE

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

I having a bunch of microservices which communicates with each other using `RestTemplate`. All the communication of microservices is from API gateway.

I am doing as following,

```
    public List<ServiceInstance> serviceInstancesByApplicationName(String applicationName) {
            return this.discoveryClient.getInstances(applicationName);
        }

    //some Other logic 

    List<ServiceInstance> apigatewaymsInstanceList = discoveryClient.getInstances(apigatewaymsName);
            ServiceInstance apigatewaymsInstance = apigatewaymsInstanceList.get(0);

    //and

    restTemplate.exchange(apigatewaymsInstance.getUri().toString() + plmpayloadprocessmsResource, HttpMethod.POST,
                                entity, String.class);
```

But here it appears like a hard code. Is there some another approach I am missing? What could be the best way ?

Likewise, I am asking is there any method available so that I can pass the name of application and eureka return me its full URI no need to do `applicationgetInstaceId(0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the EurekaClient#getNextServerFromEureka. You might have to create the URI yourself but that should be trivial.

```
@Autowired
EurekaClient eurekaClient;


public void executeMethod()     {
    InstanceInfo loadBalancedInstance = eurekaClient.getNextServerFromEureka("myService", false);
    //do work
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a reply , now can you please tell me. `loadBalancedInstance.getAppName()+"/mapping"` is it a proper way to hit the microservice.

Comment: You can get the URI from  the getHostName()  and getPort() methods

Answer (score 1):

Try using Feign - it is a declarative REST client. It does not require any boilerplate that you mentioned. Checkout spring-cloud-netflix documentation for more details. In short, your REST client would look like this:

```
@FeignClient(name = "service-name", path = "/base-path")
public interface MyClient{

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/greeting")
    String getGreeting();

}
```

Invoking **getGreeting** method would result in sending GET request to a service named **service-name** and url **/base-path/greeting**

Comment: This is not the thing what I am looking for. I want to use RestTemplate only instead of feign. I want to avoid hard code while using this restTemplate.

Comment: You mean finding service url?

Comment: Yes, I just want some method which can replace the `getInstance(0)`, Because if there are multiple instances are available I would pick up first instance only.

Comment: Then you can take advantage of *@LoadBalanced* annotation when declaring RestTemplate bean in a *@Configuration* class.